# Why can't I summon a horse in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

```
/summon EntityHorse ~ ~1 ~ {Tame:1,Saddle:1,Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:1},{Name:horse.jumpStrength,Base:2}]}
```

I've been using this command in my 1.11.2 server to summon a fast and high jumping horse but it isn't working, even if I use a command block.

Answer (score 1):

The ID of horses (and many other entities) has changed in 1.11; they are no longer `EntityHorse`.

Try the following command:

```
/summon horse ~ ~1 ~ {Tame:1,Saddle:1,Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:1},{Name:horse.jumpStrength,Base:2}]}
```